# unix sed command regular expression

Tags: regex, unix, sed, command

Can anyone explain me how the regular expression works in the sed substitute command.

```
$ cat path.txt
/usr/kbos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/jbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin
/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin/:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/omni/bin:
/opt/omni/lbin:/opt/omni/sbin:/root/bin

$ sed 's/\(\/[^:]*\).**/\1/g' path.txt
/usr/kbos/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/opt/omni/lbin
```

From the above sed command they used back reference and save operator concept.
Can anyone explain me how the regular expression especially **/[^:]*** work in the substitute command to get only the first path in each line.

Comment: `sed 's/:.*//' path.txt` would be a simpler command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wrote an extra asterisk `*` in your sed code, so it should be like this:

```
$ sed 's/\(\/[^:]*\).*/\1/g' file
/usr/kbos/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/opt/omni/lbin
```

To change the delimiter will help to understand it a little bit better:

```
sed 's#\(/[^:]*\).*#\1#g'
```

The `s#something#otherthing#g` is a basic `sed` command that looks for `something` and changes it for `otherthing` all over the file.

If you do `s#(something)#\1#g` then you "save" that `something` and then you can print it back with `\1`.

Hence, what it is doing is to get a pattern like `/[^:]*` and then print is back. `/[^:]*` means `/ and then every char except :`. So it will get `/` + all the string until it finds a semicolon `:`. It will store that piece of the string and then print it back.

Small examples:

```
# get every char
$ echo "hello123bye" | sed 's#\([a-z]*\).*#\1#g'
hello

# get everything until it finds the number 3
$ echo "hello123bye" | sed 's#\([^3]*\).*#\1#g'
hello12
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[^:]*
```

in regex would match all characters except for `:`, so it would match until this:

```
/usr/kbos/bin
```

also it would match these,

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/jbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sas/bin
```

As, these all contains characters, that are not `:`

`.*` match any character, zero or more times.

Thus, this regex `[^:]*.*`, would match all this expressions:

```
/usr/kbos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/jbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin
/usr/local/bin:/usr/jbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin
/usr/jbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin
/usr/bin:/usr/sas/bin
```

However, you get only the first field (ie,`/usr/kbos/bin`, by using back reference in `sed`), because, regular expression output the longest possible match found.